# how to open a file and take screenshot and close?

Tags: command-line

I have some pdf files in a directory. in command, how can I open and take a screenshot and close the pdf file, one by one(in fact by bash scripting)?

I think there are some command to open and close files like pdfs, but I don't know.

Comment: Are you using Ubuntu? Which release?

Comment: I use ubuntu 19.10

Comment: why taking screenshot? can not you just copy the file itself?

Answer (score 2):

This is a Simple Matter Of Programming (SMOP), but since you want to have two things happening at once (display `.pdf`, take screenshot), it's not a one-liner.

Read `man bash;man kill;man xpdf;man gnome-screenshot;man basename` and, again, `man bash`.

Then write a simple `bash` script to do what you want, something like this `./tryit`:

```bsh
#!/bin/bash
if [[ "$1" = "-d" ]] ; then
    shift
    set -x
fi

screenshotdir="/tmp/my_screenshots"
[[ -d "$screenshotdir" ]] || mkdir "$screenshotdir"

while [[ "$#" != 0 ]] ; do
    # thisone is the one we're processing this time
    thisone="$1"
    # look at a different one next time
    shift
    outfile="$( basename -s .pdf "$thisone").png" 

    # display the file, in the background
    xpdf "$thisone" &
    # remember the PID
    pidofxpdf=$!
    # give xpdf time to start
    sleep 3
    # take the screenshot
    gnome-screenshot --file="$screenshotdir/${outfile}"
    # kill the xpdf
    kill -9 $pidofxpdf
done
exit 0
```

Then make it executable

```bsh
chmod +x ./tryit
```

Finally, generate the list of filenames and feed it to `tryit`:

```bsh
find directory -maxdepth 1 -name '*.pdf' -print0 | xargs -0 -r ./tryit -d
```

Comment: !! loving it :D No idea why he wants it to actually open but you totally did what he asked :D

Answer (score 2):

In your case I would go ahead and directly convert the PDFs to images.
Install `convert`:

```
apt-get install imagemagick
```

Do the conversion for each PDF in the current directory:

```
ls *.pdf | xargs -n1 -I{} convert -density 300 {} {}.jpg
```

Comment: Does we need some additional options to convert only the first page of the pdf files?

Comment: @pa4080 This would be a new question. Unfortunately there is no parameter for convert that I'm aware of to cut out the first page.